# Unity - Повернуть объект

Tags: c#, unity3d

Чет вообще ничего не понимаю, в инете читаю про поворот объекта, и так, и сяк делаю, но не получается ничего.
Мне нужно просто повернуть объект на 180 градусов, плавность не нужна, т.к. объект телепортируется и он просто должен смотреть в другую сторону после поворота. Все мои попытки повернуть объект:

```
other.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
other.transform.localEulerAngles.y = 180;
other.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
other.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
```

Может я очень сильно туплю, но до меня не доходит, как еще можно повернуть объект, помогите поже.

Answer (score 4):

Если Вы хотите установить значение поворота используйте

```
other.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
```

Если же Вам необходимо изменить текущее значение можно воспользоваться этим способом:

```
other.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
```

Comment: Да вот я так и пробовал, но все равно ничего

Comment: @Jeep значит приводите еще код, т.к. должно, вероятно что-то возвращает положение обратно